# POST no obtiene valor de campo normal pero si de generado dinamicamente

Tags: php

Poseo estos dos campos de select, el primero articulo al cambiar llena el 2do.

AL hacer POST solo me guarda los valores de apartado (este generado dinamicamente) pero los del articulo no los guarda.

ListaArticulo:

```
function listaArticulos()
      {
      global $conexion;
      $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT numero_articulo FROM articulos");
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($stmt1);
      while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
            echo "<option value=" . $stmt1 . ">" . $stmt1 . "</option>";
            }
      $stmt->close();
      }
```

HTML
           
           Seleccione el artículo inflingido: 
           
           
           Seleccione un articulo:

```
       <select id="apartado" onchange="obtenerDesc()" name="apartado">
       <option value="0">Seleccione primero un art&iacute;culo</option>
       </select>
       </td>
       </tr>
```

POST:

```
<?php
$articulo_falta = $_POST["articulo"];
echo $articulo;
$aparte_falta = $_POST["apartado"];
echo $aparte_falta;
?>
```

Resultado:

> Undefined variable: articulo
>
> 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tus variables se llaman distinto. En vez de

```
$articulo_falta = $_POST["articulo"];
echo $articulo;
```

debiera ser

```
$articulo_falta = $_POST["articulo"];
echo $articulo_falta;
```

Comment: jejeej no me habia percatado eso, aparte con el problema real si tenian el mismo nombre pero el post no funcionaba porque el select no habia cambiado

Answer (score 0):

Tus inputs `SELECT` necesitan tener un nombre distinto o ser un array; solo están mostrando como generas un `SELECT`, si el segundo tiene el mismo nombre entonces sobreescribe la variable en `POST` al llegar a PHP.

Puedes generar tus inputs así:

```
<SELECT name="mi_nombre[]"><option>1</option>
```

En este caso  `$_POST["articulo"][0]` tendría un valor y `$_POST["articulo"][1]` otro.